# SQL Server 2012 Replication Backup and Restore

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

I am using SQL Server 2012. We have setup a replication using 'transactional with queued updating'.

If the publisher database crashes and some records in the subscriber database have not been replicated to the publisher database (and in the publisher database backup), how would we have to re-sync the data after restoring the publisher database and setting up replication without losing the new data in the subscriber database?

(And, also apply to Vice Versa case)

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this can help you : `Strategies for Backing Up and Restoring Snapshot and Transactional Replication` https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152560(v=sql.105).aspx and `Strategies for Backing Up and Restoring Merge Replication` https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152497(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Initialize SQL Server replication using a database backup

More steps at
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2386/initialize-sql-server-replication-using-a-database-backup/